# How to remove table rows by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML, I have something like:

```
<table id="registerTable">
    <tr class="leaderRegistration">
        <!--table contents-->
    </tr>
    <tr class="leaderRegistration">
        <!--table contents-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--table contents-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove certain rows of the table based on the type of user that is registering, so in my javascript I have (User.AcountType is an enum I have defined elsewhere):

```
if(newSysAdmin.accountType !== User.AccountType.Leader){
    $('#registerTable tr.leaderRegistration').remove();
}
```

However, it does not seem to be working. I have also tried selecting the rows using $('.leaderRegistration') but the result is the same. Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: I would think this would work fine. Show something reproducing the issue (like a jsFiddle). For example, it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/tptcR/ (change the newSysAdmin.accountType` to "something" and it won't remove the rows, alerting 3). JavaScript doesn't have real enums, so are you sure you're implementing it the right way?

Comment: Should work. Maybe that comparison is equal to false.

Comment: My guess is that your condition is at fault. As Ian mentioned, the row(s) should be removed with the script inside the condition.

Comment: Hm, it does get to the .remove() statement (tested using google chrome debugger), but it does not remove the items from the page. It does not seem to be an issue with the comparison, as the result was the same even when I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/WT3av/

```
<table id="registerTable">
<tr class="leaderRegistration">
    <td>Content</td>
</tr>
<tr class="leaderRegistration">
    <td>Content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Your code works. Maybe you didn't include jQuery?

Also I really hope you also check the account type on the serverside and are not sending sensitive information to the client.